# Pandas groupby and change/reassign one element

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to `groupby` given dataframe, and then, for each group, for given column `p` overwrite the value of its last element (of each group) to `1 - sum(p[:-1])` (with `sum` being the sum of all the elements apart from the last one).

Note that after performing the operation, the sum of all values in `p` for each group is equal to `1`.

For example, for this input dataframe (grouping by `c1` and `c2`):

```
  c1 c2    p
0  x  a  0.4
1  y  a  0.2
2  x  a  0.3
3  y  b  0.6
```

the expected output would be:

```
  c1 c2    p
0  x  a  0.4
1  y  a  1.0
2  x  a  0.6
3  y  b  1.0
```

I managed to perform the operation using `for` loop:

```
for _, g in df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']):
    df.loc[g.tail(1).index, 'p'] = 1 - g['p'][:-1].sum()
```

but I am looking for more elegant way of doing this, **without explicitly looping through each group**.

I tried this:

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).tail(1).index, 'p']

1    0.2
2    0.3
3    0.6

>>> 1 - df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1].sum())['p']

c1  c2
x   a     0.6
y   a     1.0
    b     1.0
```

But I don't really know how to assemble those outputs given that their indices differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible one-line solution:

```py
df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).apply(
        lambda x: x.assign(p=x['p'][:-1].tolist()+[1 - x.iloc[:-1].sum()['p']])
).reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True)
```

To make the above code more readable, here is a nearly equivalent version of my one-line solution:

```py
def func(row):
    result = 1 - row.iloc[:-1].sum()['p']
    row['p'].iloc[-1] = result
    return row

df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).apply(func)
```

With those solutions in mind, I am not entirely sure why you don't want to use the `.groupby` call in an explicit python for-loop. My hunch is that an explicit python for-loop would be more than adequate, but I don't know your specific use case/data. I would highly recommend doing some speed comparisons using `%timeit` with your specific data, as I think that will help shed light on which approach you ultimately end up using.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I did not want to use `for` loops as I thought this particular task might be efficiently and neatly solved with some one-liner. Your first solution works but agree that, arguably, might be a bit cryptic and hard to read compared to looping through the groups (but works indeed!). The latter solution (` apply(func)`) does not give an expected output and "drops" indices so I guess it would be hard to assign the resulting `p` values back to the original `df`.

Comment: I made a typo! `func` should have returned `row`, not `result`. I'll update my answer. And yeah I understand now. When working with pandas I too often search for existing api's to accomplish what I want instead of naively implementing them myself, since pandas will almost always be faster.